# Xcode App wont run on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I go to run my app and get this error
[image]

but it runs fine in Simulator anything i can do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Restart iPhone 5, Delete the same Application from iPhone 5 which is already installed.

Quit Xcode,Open Xcode,Build ->Clean Your Target, Run on iPhone 5.

Comment: Did all that. Same thing popped up. The app was never on my phone to begin with. but apart from that I did everything else